# Saving multiple animations in the same action

Tags: animation

My problem is very basic, that's why I can't find a solution on the internet.
I'm making a 2D animation in Blender. My character consists of various sprites like a thigh, calf,head, body etc. So when I animate I have to change the rotation of each sprite separately. I wanted it all to be saved under the same Action (like on YT tutorials, but they always animated only one sprite) but apparently an Action can store only one value of a transform, meaning that if I rotate the thigh at 20 degrees, the rest of the sprites would have to be rotating at 20 degrees as well to be saved under the same Action. Is there a way to save a whole animation under a specific name to be easily discerned among others in future? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, try adding some more info about your specific setup, maybe some relevant image of rig and/or settings...

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple properties animated in one action. An action will animate the same property on any object it is assigned to, this means you will need one action for each object unless you want them to move exactly the same.

The easiest solution would be to use an armature. You can parent each existing object to a single bone or you can join the objects into one, the mesh pieces don't have to be connected, and have the armature bones move different parts of the mesh. This will bring all of the animation into the one action.